# How to access internal hard drive from the terminal when booted from external drive

Tags: hard-drive

The installed OS is kubuntu, but it suddenly ceased being able to boot. I booted with Kubuntu USB drive.  I am able to see and access all the files on the internal hard drive with the graphical file manager, but I want to run TAR to capture some of the files.

The internal hard drive shows up in the graphical file manager as a device with the name 234GB Internal Drive (sda2). how can I access that hard drive from the terminal?

Comment: Find the full path of the internal drive's mount point using the GUI. This should be in the property window of the drive in Dolphin. Alternately install gnome-disks.

Comment: On the command line, `mount` will show where it's mounted (if it is).  `sudo fdisk -l` will show all the disk partitions the system sees